# PHP header redirection is not working

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header

I am working on PHP website. I've created a function to check user is logged in or not. And if user is logged in then it will fire db query and will check where to redirect user. But it is  not working properly. I've tried by changing values in mysql db but it is not working and redirecting to locations.

```
<?php
function Is_User_Logged_In()
{
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/configuration/configurationfile.php';
    if(isset( $_SESSION['uname'], $_SESSION['email']))
    {
        $uname = @$_SESSION['uname'];
        $email = @$_SESSION['email'];

        if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE BINARY `uname` = '$uname' AND `email` = '$email'"))
        {
            if($result and $result->num_rows)
            {
                $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $step2 = $result['step2'];
                $vpic = $result['vpics'];
                $act = $result['active'];

                if($step2 == 0)
                {
                    header("Location: /steptwo");
                }
                return true;
                exit();

                if($step2 != 0 && $vpic == 0)
                {
                    header("Location: /idupload");
                }
                return true;

                if($step2 != 0 && $vpic != 0 && $act == 0)
                {
                    header("Location: /pending");
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    header ("Location: /");
}
?>
```

this is my function. Default value of step2, vpics and active in database is 0. First I want to check that if step2 is zero or what. If it is zero then it should redirect to "/steptwo" page. Then I want to check vpics and then active. If three of them are not zero then home page. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Redirect directives shouldn't be inside of a function

Comment: `return true; exit()` is rather pointless. exit() can never be executed since the return call terminates the function at that point. And since return/exit is not inside the if() call, the functiont terminates regardless of what the if() test says.

Comment: these returns you have ain't looking right

Comment: can you verify your db call is returning anything?

Comment: like how? because I am logged in. So it means my db is returning.

Comment: Well, first..if `$step2` isn't equal to `0` your function does nothing because of the `return true` and `exit`. Just do a `print_r($step2)` and a `print_r($vpic);` and see what gets output

Comment: I did print_r ($step2.'<br>'.$vpic.'<br>'.$act); and got 1
0
01
0
0

Comment: just `print_r($result);` . There's no need of `return true & exit` as well.

Comment: I tried it. I also tried removing return true and exit but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning false right before your header statement.

```
return false;
header ("Location: /");
```

Should be

```
header ("Location: /");
return false;
```

**EDIT Just realized your if statements are all wonky. Change them:**

```
if($step2 == 0)
{
     header("Location: /steptwo");
     exit();
}
if($step2 != 0 && $vpic == 0)
{
     header("Location: /idupload");
     exit();
}
if($step2 != 0 && $vpic != 0 && $act == 0)
{
     header("Location: /pending");
     exit();
}
```

Comment: Will this function actually return anything or does the header() function stops the application (as of die()) ?

Comment: +1, and might as well do an `exit` after it unless the OP plans to run more code after the redirect...

Comment: @Loïc I don't think false would be returned because the header redirection part will override that part.

Comment: I made an edit to my post. Your `if` statements are really weird.

Comment: i edited return false; as you said but it didn't work and redirecting me so I was not able to see my index page too. so i had to keep it as it was and other changes I made those also did not work.

Comment: @Maximus2012: Let's make this clear: a `header('Location: ..');` does NOT make code stop running: it will run further until the webserver detects a user abort (which you can configure your browser not to do), or even untill the end it `ignore_user_abort(true);` is set. Always `exit` if the rest should not run. @OP: And why it wouldn't work: I suspect you've already generated output.

Comment: I don't know about it. I think I've got to check everything step by step. This is just simple function. I think need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($step2 == 0){
       header("Location: /steptwo");
   }return true; exit();
```

This should be

```
       if($step2 == 0){
        header("Location: /steptwo");
        exit();
      }
```

If the exit is outside if, then the lines below the if will never be executed.

Comment: put an exit(); after all header() function calls

Comment: why is he using `exit()` ?